# How to get a substring from a character on

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with a column varchar2 where I've got strings of different length and I must extract the substring after the character '-'.

```
STRING_COL
afg a ga ga ga ggfdg - gfd g f
ok k ok o - gfs gsd gsg sd g sd
okk - jdjdjdj d d
...
```

I want to get all after the '-' character

Could you tell me how to do it?
Oracle 10g

Thanks in advance!
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the good, old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination. Apply `TRIM` if you want to remove leading/trailing spaces.

```
SQL> select string_col,
  2    substr(string_col, instr(string_col, '-') + 1) result,
  3    --
  4    trim(substr(string_col, instr(string_col, '-') + 1)) trimmed_result
  5  from test;

STRING_COL                                         RESULT               TRIMMED_RESULT
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
afg a ga ga ga ggfdg - gfd g f                      gfd g f             gfd g f
ok k ok o - gfs gsd gsg sd g sd                     gfs gsd gsg sd g sd gfs gsd gsg sd g sd
okk - jdjdjdj d d                                   jdjdjdj d d         jdjdjdj d d

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm):

```
select regexp_substr(string_col, '[^-]+$')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9535f164fca16d23eafaeddc4be8410b) is a db<>fiddle.